# MacOSx - Compiling a C project using make command

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos, makefile

I am working on an assignment for my System Programming course which is a course using the linux terminal and C language. I own a mac and already require a windows VM for my other courses so I have no room for the linux machine and my professor said that my mac machine would work fine as it has the linux terminal.

We have to create a makefile file that will compile and link the c project together and create a .bin file, which is the basis of programming C in a linux environment, but I am getting errors with my makefile.

I believe it has to do with the difference between Linux and MacOS but I am not sure.

My makefile is as follows:

```
./bin/cryptoMagic: ./obj/main.o
cc ./obj/main.o -o ./bin/cryptoMagic

./obj/main.o: ./src/main.c ./inc/prototypes.h
cc ./src/main.c -c -o ./obj/main.o
```

When I run the make utility in the terminal I get this error message:

```
kyles-MacBook-Pro:~ KyleJensen$ cd Documents/School/First\     Year/Semester2/SystemProgramming/Assignments/Assign01/
kyles-MacBook-Pro:Assign01 KyleJensen$ make
cc ./obj/main.o -o ./bin/cryptoMagic
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_main", referenced from:
 implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see    invocation)
make: *** [bin/cryptoMagic] Error 1
```

Comment: It does not look like a Linux/Mac issue. At least you need to recompile main.c first. Review the documentation for cc.

Comment: Have you got `bin`, `obj`, `inc` and `src` subdirectories? Does your `main.c` contain a `main(int argc,char*argv[])` function? Can you add `-I inc` to tell the compiler where your include files are?

Comment: smell like there is no 'main' entry point in main.c - can we see it please

Comment: Wow I'm retarted. Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake I hadn't written anything in the C file LOL.

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. I didn't have a valid main function in my C file. Watch out for this one in the future kids!